# how to get file info returned after sending it to another php file using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file

The code i have written is to send any uploaded file to a php page. I want the response to be an array containing all the information about that file. Also i have used "POST" method to upload a file.Is it ok?

i want a neat and clean array which will contain information about the file ,like name,size,type etc. But i am getting an array like the following:

[image]

How i can manage that? full code:

fileupload.php file :

```
<?php  ?>
<html>
<body>

<input type='file' id='up' name='image'>
<div id='imageholder' style='width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid black;'></div>
<span id='info' style='color:red;'></span>
<script>


function fileread(event){

  if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {


  /* Handle local files */

        var file = event.target.files[0];
        var formdata=new FormData();
        formdata.append(document.getElementById('up').name,file,file.name);


                var xhr=new  XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(e){
                    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
                          console.log(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
                xhr.open('post',"../practice/classes/testimag.php",true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.send(formdata);



    }else {
     // File and Blob are not supported
            console.log('file and blob is not supported');
       } 



  } 

    document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('change',fileread,false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

testimag.php file :

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you check if the information you want is inside $_FILES variable?

Answer (score 2):

You could just parse the array containing the data as JSON on the server

```
<?php  

   $arr = array();


    if( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] ) == 'post' && !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
       foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {

           $finfo = finfo_open();
           $data  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
           finfo_close($finfo);

           array_push($arr, $data);
       }

       echo json_encode($arr);
    } else {
       echo '{"error" : "no files"}';
    }

?>
```

and in your javascript parse it back to an array/object

```
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(e){
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
         var obj = JSON.parse( xhr.response );
    }
}
```

This assumes you're already getting the file serverside, which your screenshot of an array suggests.

---

Newer browser *(Chrome >31, Firefox >10, no IE)* support setting the responseType to get content automatically parsed

```
var xhr = new  XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange=function(e){
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
        console.log(xhr.response); // array / object
    }
}

xhr.open('post',"../practice/classes/testimag.php",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.responseType = "json";

xhr.send(formdata);
```

Comment: i am getting this error  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Then you're not returning valid JSON. You can't echo anything other than the JSON, and no spaces etc.

Comment: you're trying to JSON encode an entire file. this is not useful in any way and it's not what he's asking for.

Comment: and it's not valid JSON becuase it's probably too big to be passed back to the browser so the request is getting truncated.

Comment: still can't understand . i did as you suggested . Then what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I assumed the OP already had an array. Added code to get the info from a file.

Comment: $_FILES array supposed to be empty ?right?  i am not getting any result still. Same error happening over and over again :(

Answer (score 0):

Files are passes to PHP via `$_FILES`, not via `$_POST`. If you want info about the file, use this.. The `$_FILES` array already contains info about the mimetype and size of the upload.

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

However, if this is all you need, you don't need ajax. Newer versions of Javascript let you get this info right from the browser.

Comment: i had to use post method in ajax request. So file array should be empty ,shouldn't it ?

Comment: No, POST is the correct method. There is no such thing as a "FILES" method. that's just where the upload data goes.